Generate Quasi Random Numbers for a Multivariate Distribution Using Copulas
Consider a sequence $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$ of $\mathbb R^d$-valued quasi random vectors (e.g., Halton). Given a multivariate distribution $F$, I want to generate samples from $F$. In a question I asked a couple of weeks ago (Generate Quasi Random Numbers for a Multivariate DIstribution), @whuber suggested using a copula to sample from $F$.
I worked out that I could use the R package copula and its member function cCopula with option inverse = TRUE to compute the inverse $C^-(u_p, | u_1, u_2, ..., u_{p-1})$ of the conditional distribution function of the copula $C$ for $p = 1,2,\dots,d$. Here $u := (u_1, u_2, ..., u_d)$ denotes an realization of $U_i$.
Let's say $C$ is the t copula with correlation matrix $\Omega$ and $\nu$ degrees of freedom. I realized that the output of cCopula with inverse = TRUE yields values that are between zero and one. These values are certainly not values from a multivariate t distribution. Do I have to compute the (univariate) inverse cumulative distribution function (i.e., the quantile) for each of these values? That is, sample from multivariate t by computing $$C^-\big(t_\nu(U_{i,p})|t_\nu(U_{i,1}),t_\nu(U_{i,2}),\dots,t_\nu(U_{i,p-1})\big)$$ for each $p = 1,2,\dots,d$ and each $i = 1,2,\dots, n$ with $t_\nu$ denoting the quantile function of a univariate t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.
More generally, if I believe that $F$ with marginals $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_d$ can be expressed by a copula $C$, then sampling from $F$ is done by computing $$C^-\big(F_p^-(U_{i,p})| F_1^-(U_{i,1}),F_2^-(U_{i,2}),\dots,F_{p-1}^-(U_{i,p-1})\big)$$ for each $p = 1,2,\dots,d$ and each $i = 1,2,\dots, n$ with $F_i^-$ denoting the inverse of $F_i$.
Are these thoughts correct?

Yes, you got it right. The copula only captures the dependence structure, i.e. the joint distribution of the random variables transformed to the unit cube. To get the marginal behavior you want, you have to quantile transform the samples, i.e. apply $F_i^{-}$ to the samples corresponding to the random variables.
The reason why people use copulas is that, using them, the dependence structure and the marginal distribution can be disentangled. Meaning, that you could also apply the quantile transformation with lets say the exponential distribution quantile function, then you would get a multivariate distribution with dependence structure like the t-distribution (so heavy tails) and marginal behavior as the exponential distribution. If you just want the multivariate t-distribution, then the univariate quantile function of the t-distribution is the correct choice.
